# Multiple child components in parent component have the same instance angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I have a child component `file-upload` which i use in parent component multiple times like below

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Input Files</legend>

    <file-upload id="s" imgpath="Image/saham.png" title="saham"></file-upload>
    <file-upload id="q" imgpath="Image/sandoq.png" title="sandoq"></file-upload>
    <file-upload id="o" imgpath="Image/oraq.png" title="oraq"></file-upload>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="save()" [disabled]="!cansave">Save</button>
</fieldset>
```

in UI everything is fine, but in action it seems that there is only one object instance of `file-upload` which  is working and every input changes in each of `file-upload` components applies only to one of them(the first one).

the problem is for `input` and the way I am using it..when i use a simple button, every thing is fine. here is the html of `file-upload`

```
    <div class="upload" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (drop)="drop($event)">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    <div class="drop-zone" [ngClass]="{'showdropzone' : showdropzone}">
        Drop Here Or...
        <div class="clickhere">
            <label for="files">Click Here</label>
            <input id="files" type="file" class="file" (change)="fileSelect($event)"><!--does not work-->
            <button (click)="fileSelect($event)">Click Me</button> <!--this is working-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <circle-progress class="myprogress" #circleProg1 [percent]="50" [ngClass]="{'showprogress' : showprogress}"></circle-progress>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign status"  [ngClass]="{'warninput' : haswarning}"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle status"     [ngClass]="{'successinput' : succeeded}"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You should share an example with Plunkr. There's not enough code to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Are the `file-upload` components sharing a service or something?

Comment: can you share the code in the .ts file?

Comment: @rinukkusu , no, it is just using a service for uploading on server

Comment: @RaedKhalaf I've shared the ts of both child and parent

Comment: @Parid0kht : All your `file-upload` components are sharing the same instance of the service `HomeService`.

Comment: @talentedandrew , I dont understand, because the `HomeService` is in the parent..and there is nothing to do with `file-upload`

Comment: @Parid0kht : try injecting the service in each `file-upload` component.I dont know the name of the service which you are mentioning thats why I wrote `HomeService`. I mean to say the file service

Comment: @Parid0kht can you remove the `id` from the `input` tag and try accessing the `input` by setting a local variable in the `input` tag (Like this https://plnkr.co/edit/RJJdcY?p=preview)

Comment: @talentedandrew yes, i tried dynamic `id` and i works.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers, not as updates to the question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @Parid0kht : good, now please post your solution, how you did that , so that anyone struggling in this in future can get a help from this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **singleton** FileService that's why they all have the same instance of that service. I am assuming you inject your provider in your AppModule, so remove it and try to inject your service at the component level like this

```
@Component){
  providers: [FileService]
  ...
}
export class FileUploadComponent
```

For more information about multiple service instances, take a look at this [from official docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#multiple-service-instances-sandboxing).
Hope this helps

Comment: Only the `url` field of the `FileService` is being used - do you really think, that's the problem?

Comment: @rinukkusu it doesn't matter if you use just the url field of the FileService, if it's a singleton, your child components will share this instance. Have you tried my answer? :)

Comment: i've tried the answer..but it is not because of this..I 've found the problem but I do not know how to solve it. it is in html of file-uploader and it is because of the `input`.. i've updated my question to show the exact problem @brijmcq

Comment: @Parid0kht it would be nice if you'll share the component code